# Doing the ones complement on an int and uint

Tags: c#

I am trying to understand the following:

int 19 in binary is 10011
uint 19 in binary is 10011

so when I do the ~ operation on the int 19 it becomes -20

~19 int in binary is 11111111111111111111111111101100
~19 uint in binary is 11111111111111111111111111101100

But if I output this, the int ~19 becomes -20
and the uint ~19 becomes 4294967276

I mean how does this work in terms of ones and zeros?
How does It know which is the minus sign in int and uint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **type** of a variable [stores information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/) about its representation (and therefore, its interpretation). If the type is `int`, the program will know how to interpret whatever is stored in memory for that `int`.

---

When you do 1's complement of (19)<sub>10</sub>, you get:

> (0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0011)<sub>2</sub> = (19)<sub>10</sub>
>
> (1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110 1100)<sub>2</sub> = ~(19)<sub>10</sub>

In C#, [2's complement is used for `int` representation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#working-with-non-decimal-32-bit-integer-values), which means that the most significant bit will represent the sign of a variable (1 is negative), and the value is calculated by complementing each bit and adding 1 ([more on Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)):

> (1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110 1100)<sub>2</sub> -> in the memory location for an `int`
>
> (0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0011)<sub>2</sub> -> complement of whatever is in memory for that `int`
>
> +1
>
> =
> (0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0100)<sub>2</sub> = (20)<sub>10</sub>

Therefore giving us the `-20` in the `int` variable.

---

As for the `uint` variable, there's no sign, no 2's complement, so the whole 32 bits are used for the value.

> (1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110 1100)<sub>2</sub> = ~(19)<sub>10</sub> = (4 294 967 276)<sub>10</sub>

Comment: thank you very much, this was really helpful. I have only one question remaining.
I have checked and I can negate a uint value and the system does that by doing the 2s complement and the output is the same as with the int but with twice as many 1s in the beginning 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111101101. By the way I am talking about the value 19. Why do we have this many 1s in the beginning? Why can I negate a uint if It is unsigned? How does this work?
Sorry this was 3 questions)

Comment: You already got the answer in @Guru Stron's comments, I might just add the reason behind that. Imagine having the largest `uint` value. Negating that, you would expect to get the same value with a negative sign. Because that value is too large for an `int`, it has to be stored as a `long`. That's why an [implicit conversion from `uint` to `int` is not available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/numeric-conversions#implicit-numeric-conversions).

Answer (score 1):

There is no minus sign in [`uint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types) cause it is literally *unsigned* 32-bit integer. As for the `int` - first bit is responsible for sign of the number (`0` is positive, `1` is negative). Both numbers in the binary form have the same representation:

```cs
int x = 19;
uint y = 19;
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(~x, toBase: 2)); //      prints 11111111111111111111111111101100
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(unchecked((int)~y), toBase: 2)); // also prints 11111111111111111111111111101100
```

Comment: Thank you very much. So I have noticed that I can negate a uint. Why is that? Why can I do that if It is unsigned?

Comment: @EricMovsessian negated `uint` results in `long` which is pretty much signed.

Comment: Thank you, sorry for the question, It was a silly one.

Comment: @EricMovsessian This site is created for questions so no problem at all. Was glad to help!